# AHK Excel COM - Change color within a sheet

Tags: excel, com, autohotkey

Hello stackoverflow members,

I have an Excel worksheet where specific cells have a red border and also red font size.
At the moment, I'm looking for a way to replace the red color by another one, e.g. blue.

Since I do not have any VBA knowledge, I'm trying to realize this with AutoHotkey and its COM support.
I've made some progress!
However, even though it works, it doesn't change borders of several cells.
The same for font colors - some get changed, others don't get changed.

That's my code:

```
    F1::
xl := ComObjActive("Excel.Application") ; Connect to Excel
ws := xl.ActiveSheet ; Connect to worksheet
column = 65 ; ASCCI code
Loop, 800
{
  r++ ; row 1
  if (r = 41) ; If row 41 was reached:
  {
    r = 1 ; Go back to row 1
    column := column + 1 ; Next column
  }
  c := Chr(column) ; ASCCI to String
  cell = %c%%r% ; Cell = e.g. A1, etc.
  ;if xl.range(cell).Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Color = 0x0000FF ; If border color is red - TYPE CONFLICT!
  if xl.range(cell).Borders.Color = 0x0000FF ; If border color is red: - WORKS PARTLY
  {
    ;xl.range(cell).Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Color := 0xFFD700 ; Set blue color - I DOUBT IT WILL WORK!
    xl.range(cell).Borders.Color := 0xFFD700 ; Set to blue - WORKS PARTLY
  }
  if xl.range(cell).Font.Color = 0x0000FF ; If font color is red:  - WORKS PARTLY
  {
    xl.range(cell).Font.Color := 0xFFD700 ; Set to blue - WORKS PARTLY
  }
}
return
```

As you can see, I already tried it with if xl.range(cell).Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Color = 0x0000FF
which doesn't seem to work.
It says, "TYPE CONFLICT".

On this screenshot you can see all the successful color adjustments (blue).
The rest, which is red, was not changed.
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2o06.png)

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved.

```
for xlCell in xl.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells ; Used cells
{
  for xlBorder in xlCell.Borders ; Where borders are used
  {
    if (xlBorder.Color = 0x0000FF) ; Red
    {
      xlBorder.Color := 0x5FD200 ; Green
    }
    if (xlCell.Font.Color = 0x0000FF) ; Red
    {
      xlCell.Font.Color := 0x5FD200 ; Green
    }
  } 
}
for xlShape in xl.ActiveSheet.Shapes ; Used shapes
{
  if (xlShape.Line.ForeColor.RGB = 0x0000FF) ; Red
  {
    xlShape.Line.ForeColor.RGB := 0x5FD200 ; Green
  }
}
```

Thanks anyway.

P.S. For the font color within a text there is no solution.